# How to reference to a Method inside a Class in urls.py

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have this `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from forms import ReferenceTableForm

class ReferenceTable(object):
    def createReferenceTable(request):
        form = ReferenceTableForm()
        return render(request, "DataImport/createReferenceTable.html", {'form': form})
```

And this is my `urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.createReferenceTable),
)
```

But when I go to my url, `http://localhost:8000/create_reference_table/` (I am using a different `urls.py` for each app), I get this error:

```
'module' object has no attribute 'createReferenceTable'
```

If I move the method `createReferenceTable` to out of the class, it works fine.

I think it is because as I am calling a method that is inside a class it is expecting it to be called from an instance of this class, but as I am not very experienced, I really  don't know how to sort it out (either if it is the problem or not).

Could someone explain what is going on and how I can solve it and prevent from happening next time?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try viewing it using this url `http://localhost:8000/` or you can just assign the url to `url(r'^create_reference_table/$', views.createReferenceTable),`

Comment: It won't work because as I said I am using a different urls.py for each app. In the main urls.py I have `url(r'^create_reference_table/', include('DataImport.urls'))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the method static:

```
class ReferenceTable(object):

    @staticmethod
    def createReferenceTable(request):
        ...
```

And then add the class name in `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^$', views.ReferenceTable.createReferenceTable),
```

Answer (score -1):

You can write `ref = RefrenceTable()` in your views, and write `ref.createRefrenceTable` in your urls, of course, `from views import ref`

Comment: I did it, but then I get the error: `'ReferenceTable' object has no attribute 'META'`

Comment: I put the `ref = ReferenceTable()` at the end of the `views.py`

Comment: yes, Because you are not a member  method， you should add self in argument or use @staticmethod

Comment: Don't do this. You'll end up with one instance shared across requests, which is rarely desirable and will probably end up with thread-safety issues.